# Flask WTF cannot find a value to populate from the provided obj or input data/defaults

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm using python Flask with WTForm and I'm having serious issues with the [`populate_obj` method](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/#wtforms.form.Form.populate_obj):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/app/my_data/main.py", line 29, in submit
    form.populate_obj(demande)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 95, in populate_obj
    field.populate_obj(obj, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 877, in populate_obj
    raise TypeError('populate_obj: cannot find a value to populate from the provided obj or input data/defaults')
TypeError: populate_obj: cannot find a value to populate from the provided obj or input data/defaults
```

Here's my code (nothing fancy):

```
    form = DemandeForm(data=request.form)
    if form.validate():
        form.populate_obj(demande)
        flash('Enregistré', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

I could detail all the forms fields, but this would be tedious. My guess is that this as to do with nested forms I'm using:

```
class DemandeForm(BaseForm):
    AdressePrivee = FormField(AdresseForm)
    AdresseProfessionnelle = FormField(AdresseForm)
    Prestations = FieldList(FormField(PrestationForm), min_entries=1)
```

So my questions are:

- why is the error rising?
- how can I have more explicit error, telling me which fields are raising the issue?
- how can I solve this?

I'm completely locked right now :(

Thanks for support

---

#### EDIT

So I finally managed to confirm that the issue comes from the `FormField(AddressField)`.

Here's my `Demande` model extract:

```
    AdressePrivee = db.relationship(AdressePrivee, backref='Demande', lazy=False, uselist=False)
```

And in `DemandeForm`:

```
    AdressePrivee = FormField(AdresseForm)
```

Wtform is not happy because `demande.AdressePrivee` == `None`, hence `self._obj is None` in the code and the error rises.

I tried to add default value:

```
    AdressePrivee = FormField(AdresseForm, default=AdressePrivee())
```

But then I get an error while saving, as `AddressePrivee` fields are empty while they shouldn't...

Ain't there a missing option, like `nullable: True` or something? I'm not sure it makes sense that the error rises, nor how I can handle this situation...

Thanks

Comment: Where does demande come from ? Is it defined elsewhere ?

Comment: `demande` is actually the current user from `flask_login` :-D

Comment: Let me know if you need me to detail all the fields.

Comment: Are you sure that the variable demande is actually holding a value ? Your code doesn't show it. It appears that there is something wrong with this variable so you should inspect it.

Comment: Yes it does: `<Demande 111 Nom1 Prénom1>`. Comes from `from flask_login import current_user as demande`

Comment: Hey @Anonymous, I just edited my question with details. Would you mind having a look? Thanks a lot

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve by using `form.populate_obj(demande)`. You are not even saving the data to DB as per your ORM model. Maybe you should post complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant source code for the WTF function, this is where the error is triggered:

```
def populate_obj(self, obj, name):
    candidate = getattr(obj, name, None)
    if candidate is None:
        if self._obj is None:
            raise TypeError('populate_obj: cannot find a value to populate from the provided obj or input data/defaults')
        candidate = self._obj
        setattr(obj, name, candidate)

    self.form.populate_obj(candidate)
```

[Source](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/_modules/wtforms/fields/core/)

`self._obj` is assigned a value in the routine `process`.

So it seems that there is something wrong with the variable you are passing. In fact I don't understand why you are passing the equivalent of `current_user` to your form. Look [here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/?highlight=populate_obj#wtforms.form.Form.populate_obj) for an example of usage.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How come there are two attributes there (in addition to `self`)? In your usage example, there is only `obj`.  Shouldn't the error print the content of the `name` variable at least?